# How to add custom whitespace between XML attributes (.NET, Powershell)

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm in PowerShell, manipulating xml documents (.NET's System.Xml.XmlDocument class).  I want to add custom white space between xml attributes.  I can't find an API call for it in .NET, and nobody online seems to be trying to do this.  Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do, but with a comment where I don't know what to call:

```
$xmlDoc = [xml]@"
<root>
    <test Id="1" a="a" b="b" />
    <test Id="2" a="a" b="b" />
</root>
"@
$elements = @($xmlDoc.SelectNodes('//*'))
foreach($element in $elements)
{
    $attributes = $element.Attributes
    foreach($attribute in $attributes)
    {
        #
        # How do I access the whitespace around the attributes?
        #
    }
}

# Output to screen exactly what will be saved to disk
$tempFile = [System.IO.FileInfo]([System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName())
$xmlDoc.save($tempFile)
foreach($line in (Get-Content $tempFile))
    { Write-Host $line }
Remove-Item $tempFile
```

Does anyone know how to access the whitespace around a System.Xml.XmlAttribute?

Comment: Why doesn't matter.  If there's no .NET API for it, then that would be the answer.  If you're sure of that, feel free to post it.

Comment: Why _does_ matter. It may be possible to solve your actual problem some other way. XML doesn't _have_ whitespace around attributes.

Comment: XML does indeed have white space around attributes.  If you *don't* have whitespace between attributes, it's not valid XML.  `<element a="a"b="b" />` is invalid for lack of whitespace.

Comment: @JohnB that is right, but XmlDocument will allways be serialized as a valid XML. so why should you care about whitespaces?

Comment: Since people are curious, I'm doing something similar to "HTML Tidy", but for XML, and the built-in .NET facilities for attribute formatting don't behave the way I need them to.  I am aware of XmlWriterSettings to get things formatted, but it isn't doing what I need to do. But regardless, I'm not asking how to differently solve my programming problem.  I'm asking about the power or limitations of the "System.Xml" API.  This is useful for my own curiosity and for the sake of others who stumble on this looking to do the same thing.

Comment: Edit: To be more accurate, I'm doing something more like Resharper's code formatting (which has a similar purpose to "HTML Tidy").  I need code that is more human readable and produces smaller diffs in our version control system.  Our developers use Resharper and then commit changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do it using [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) (and related) or [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) (and related). Even such low level thing like [XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w703ce6s.aspx) does not allow you to add additional whitespaces or new lines between attributes.

Every XmlNode/XObject serializable, so you can write your own special-formatted-serialization or post-process the resulting XML after the standard serialization process. Hope this helps